# customising plone breadcrumbs and moving out of plone top

Tags: view, plone, zope, breadcrumbs

The plone guy is on leave, I have a request to add breadcrumbs to a plone 3 site. 
Normally in plone the logo, navigation search personal bar and breadcrumbs are all in a view called plonetop
This view has been replaced with straight html because it was too hard to modify plones default plonetop view.

There is a view in portal_view_customizations called path_bar, it contains the breadcrumb view. I want to display this on the site but I don't know how to call it. it appears I need to create a custom view and create a new section in configure.zcml but I really don't know where to start.

can anyone help?

To reiterate I want to place the plone path bar onto the page without all the other plone top stuff just the path_bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I fell back to the plone 2 way of doing it. Because plone3 is backward compatible I was able to simply drop the plone 2 macro where I wanted it and voila! it worked.

Plone 3 is simply too hard to work with.